# ShinyAlert goes wrong with local image (order of execution)

Tags: r, shiny, imageurl

I've run into the following problem

using ShinyAlert * if I add an imageUrl to the message, if it's an internet url address, no problem, the message appears, image appears instantly, and then the other code pieces run, 
BUT
if it is an image on my harddisk, this happens: 
Message without image opens
other code after the message runs
THEN the image appears..

I'm clueless why and I've tried it on 3 different computers now, and tested it with js swal approach as well, same problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(sweetalertR)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  useShinyalert(),
  textInput("expr", label = "Enter an R expression",
            value = "bio",width="600px"),

  actionButton(inputId ="mybutton", "Run")


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shinyEnv <- environment()

  observeEvent(input$mybutton, {
    print(getwd())
    shinyalert(title = 'hello', imageUrl ="insert http url or local disk path/name.png", imageSize = "80x80")

    for (i in 1:50000){ print(i)  ### see if picture in message shows up before this code runs
      }
    })
  }



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

EXTRA example how I code it with a jscode

```
swal5 = function(params) { 
      var defaultParams = {
        title : null,
        text : null,
        type : null  
      };
      params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
      swal({title : params.title, text : params.text, type : params.type,
        showCancelButton : true,
        cancelButtonText : "No, cancel please!",
        showConfirmButton : true,
        confirmButtonText : "Yes, merge the files!",
        closeOnCancel : true,
        closeOnConfirm: false},
        evalFunction = function(isConfirm){
          if (isConfirm === true) {
            var val1= 1;
            Shiny.onInputChange("MergeRaw_OP", [val1, Math.random()]);}

        });
    };
```

Comment: works fine for me, the image shows up right away

Comment: I just ran it on a computer that had never had R on it before, with only the bare minimum packages installed, again same problem. Local disk image does appear, but only after the print 1:50000 has finished. make it a larger nr if you need to see clearer in which order it goes as 50k can be printed quit fast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code (at least the first one, haven't tried the second one) isn't actually right and has a lot of extra code that doesn't do anything. No need to load shinyjs, shinydashboard, to save the environment, and `sweetalertR` is the wrong package. When I try to run the correct and minimal version of that code chunk, it does work for me.

```
library(shinyalert)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyalert(),
  actionButton(inputId ="mybutton", "Run")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$mybutton, {
    shinyalert(title = 'hello', imageUrl ="http://deanattali.com/img/deanimg.jpeg", imageSize = "80x80")
    for (i in 1:50000){ print(i) }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes, that works for me too. However, now try to store that same image and run it from a disk location rather than an internet address. 
First of all, as a 1 page app, I can't get it to even load the picture at all. Either by doing setwd("pathto....../Desktop/") and then imageUrl= "deanattali.jpeg", or by imageUrl = "pathto..../Desktop/deanimg.jpeg"
If I save the app as server.R and ui.R, and make a www folder inside the app folder, put the image there, then use setwd() and imageUrl = "deanimg.jpeg" it does work partially, but then the image renders after the for print loop, which is weird.

Comment: I see. If you look at the HTML source before the image appears, you can see that the HTML for the image is actually there. I never noticed this specific problem before but it seems like it's a browser/shiny issue. Looks like Shiny is busy and can't fetch the image until its process is done. This is a problem that happens often in shiny when sending messages to javascript and require flushing. The workaround solution I generally use is to wrap the second expression in a shinyjs::delay, for example `shinyjs::delay(1,{for (i in 1:50000){ print(i) }})`, so that the first expression will complete

Comment: Cool, learned another thing. I will try that. Thanks for helping Dean!

Comment: Dean, just had another look at this, am I correct that the shinyalert package can't handle the evalFunction code, and also doesn't allow argument for cancelButtonColor?

Comment: You're correct the the cancel button colour cannot be changed using the options, but you're free to use CSS for that. To evaluate code as a result on user action, you can use the `callbackR` or `callbackJS` arguments. The sweetalert package has gone through a major update recently so the API is likely to change once I update the package to reflect the new javascript library

Comment: I will have a look at it then in a while. How about documentation and examples? I remember you mentioning you lost that on a package you build in a mail once

Comment: there is some (minimal) documentation that describes what the many parameters do. But yes I do need to add proper documentation - even the DESCRIPTION file isn't ready! This package is 100% a work in progress and not meant to be used by the public yet, so until it's ready, it's use-at-your-own-risk. My days are absolutely packed and I have quite a few side projects, this one being one of them, so I'll release it when I find the time :)